# Link Button disappears when Post Back occurs

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I create a link button and put an image on it.

Here is my code:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" Text="">
        <asp:Image ID="Image1" ImageUrl="" runat="server" />
</asp:LinkButton>
```

And here is my subsequent C# code:

```
if(!Page.IsPostBack)
{
   LinkButton1.OnClientClick = "ClientClick()";
   Image1.ImageUrl = "~/Images/embed.png";
}
```

I provide the ImageUrl from the c# code behind for the Image and add an OnClientClick event from c# code for the Link Button. When the page first load then the button showed properly.

My browser rendered HTML before post back

```
<a onclick="ClientClick();" id="MainContent_LinkButton1" 
href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$MainContent$LinkButton1','')">
<img id="MainContent_Image1" src="Images/embed.png">
</a>
```

When I press any button in this page and PostBack occurs, then the button disappears but I don't do anything in my code behind for that button for PostBack.

My browser rendered HTML after post back

```
<a onclick="ClientClick();" id="MainContent_LinkButton1" 
href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$MainContent$LinkButton1','')">
</a>
```

If I do not add OnClientClick or Text for the Link Button then the image does not disappear.Or if I set ViewState false for link button then image does not disappear. So why this button disappear when page is PostBack?

Comment: Have you not repeated the question twice and deleted the previous one?

Comment: If you have deleted a previous answer you should prob know that; [that will still be counted towards a potential question ban](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th)

Comment: Your question is not clear at all. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

With `EnableViewState="true"` this code works correct even with post back and the image is shown

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" Text="">
        <asp:Image ID="Image1" ImageUrl="" runat="server" />
</asp:LinkButton>


if(!Page.IsPostBack)
{
   LinkButton1.OnClientClick = "ClientClick()";
   Image1.ImageUrl = "~/Images/embed.png";
}
```

With `EnableViewState="false"` You must remove the `IsPostBack` because is not saved anywhere and you need to add it again

```
// remove that check if EnableViewState is false
//if(!Page.IsPostBack)
{
   LinkButton1.OnClientClick = "ClientClick()";
   Image1.ImageUrl = "~/Images/embed.png";
}
```

Comment: Hi @Aristos I applied the first step that you said. I do nothing with view state. I simply add OnclientClick and provide ImageUrl for image button and problem happened.

Comment: @GaziEnosis You have somewhere disable the viewstate. Or you may have other code that reset the img. In any case what I say here stands and this is it - with out any question about. So look and search your code for bugs

Comment: I do not disable the viewstate anywhere. I just create a new WebForm project. And simply add this lines of code I mention at my question.

Comment: @GaziEnosis Ok remove then the IsPostBack and it will work

Comment: Now my .cs page is: 

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {          
                LinkButton1.OnClientClick = "ClientClick()";
                Image1.ImageUrl = "~/Images/embed.png";
        }

and in my .aspx page is:

<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" Text="">
        <asp:Image ID="Image1" ImageUrl=""  runat="server" />
    </asp:LinkButton>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server">LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>

But till button disappear when I click LinkButton2 and PostBack happened.

Answer (score -1):

This occurs because Postback clears all the control of your asp.net page.

To retain controls from previous load, you need to make sure that whatever code is in Page_Load() is re-executed on "Button_click" which causes postback.

```
void button_click()
{
// do stuff

page_load(Dummy Object);

}
```